# Including objects binding in MultiBinding command parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, contextmenu, multibinding

I am attempting to use a `<MultiBinding>` to pass two parameters to my ViewModel's command but am having issues getting the XAML parser to accept my attempts.

Consider the following ListView contained within my `UserControl` which is bound to a collection of `Ticket` objects.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvTicketSummaries" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TicketSummaries}"  
                  ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ListViewItem}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

The respective style `ListViewItem`

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=cmListViewItem}"/>
    <!-- A load of irrelevant stuff ->
</Style>
```

And the referenced `ContextMenu`  item where the source of my query sits;

```
<!-- ContextMenu DataContext bound to UserControls view model so it can access 'Agents' ObservableCollection -->    
<ContextMenu x:Key="cmListViewItem" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext}">
    <MenuItem Header="Send as Notification" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Agents}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <!-- Display the name of the agent (this works) -->
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <!-- Set the command to that of one on usercontrols viewmodel (this works) -->
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext.SendTicketNotification}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TicketNotificationParameterConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <!-- This SHOULD be the Agent object I clicked on to trigger the Command. This does NOT work, results in either exception or 'UnsetValue' -->
                                <Binding Source="{Binding}" />
                                <!-- Also pass in the Ticket item that was clicked on to open the context menu, this works fine -->
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}" Path="SelectedItem" />
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

So here is what I am attempting to do;

- The context menu has a single item "Send ticket as notification" which, when selected, lists all the available `Agents` which can receive said notification. This works.
- When I click on one of these agent options, I want the context menu item to send both the `ticket` item that was clicked on from the `listview` to show the context menu (this works) AND the `Agent` item I selected from the context menu.  I have half-achieved this with the `MultiBinding`

  ```
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TicketNotificationParameterConverter}">
                          <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                              <!-- This works, it sends the Ticket object to the Converter -->
                              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}" Path="SelectedItem" />
                              <!-- This caused an exception saying that I can only set 'Path' property on DependencyProperty types -->
                              <Binding Path="{Binding}" />
                          </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                      </MultiBinding>
  ```

Now although the actual set-up of the context menu seems some what complicated to me.  The actual specification that one of the `MultiBinding` parameters should be the actual item bound to the clicked `ContextMenu.MenuItem` seems quite a simple command.  The context menu correctly lists all Agents and so I would of thought that simply asking for this current object to be sent through as a command parameter, simple.  I have also tried;

```
<Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}} Path="SelectedItem" />
```

as well as

```
<Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}} Path="SelectedItem" />
```

But all that gets sent to the Parameter converter is `UnsetValue`

Thank you for your time and any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 3):

This line is odd:

```
<Binding Path="{Binding}" />
```

Is the current DataContext a string that would suffice as a path that would find something in the current DataContext which is in fact *not a string* after all? Makes perfect sense.

Did you mean to do this instead which binds to the DataContext?

```
<Binding />
```